# How to write update query in WordPress to expire transients

Tags: query, transient

I want to write update query to expire transients . I will upadte their time to 1 in wordpress option table.

My query for update is

```
$wpdb->update( 
    'options', 
    array( 
        'option_value' => '1',  // string

    ), 
    array( 'option_name' => '%re_compare%' )

);
```

Its not working . 
Basically I want to remove / Expire already existing transients.

But if I delete transients from options table they still show in transient manager plugin. So thought to set their expire time to 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

Transients are not guaranteed to use database at all. They will use object cache if it is enabled.

And since there is no bulk delete in object cache API, effectively there is no reliable way to clear out transients across all possible environments.

There are some *performance* reasons to clear them out of database (which core is now doing on upgrades), but your program *logic* should stay away from it.

As for why specifically it fails in your case it is hard to say. You would need to determine what storage is being used and resulting raw SQL query to test.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting transients following way. It should work.

```
global $wpdb; 
$sql = 'DELETE FROM ' . $wpdb->options . ' WHERE option_name LIKE "_transient_%"'; 
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

Or you can try this plugin to delete expired transients

https://wordpress.org/plugins/delete-expired-transients/

**Edit** : To update transient value to 1 use following Query

```
$sql = 'UPDATE ' . $wpdb->options . ' SET option_value = 1 WHERE option_name LIKE "_transient_%"';
```

I just tried deleting transient data using above query and it deleted 1500+ rows from options table. So quoery should work. May be your site is using object cache to store transient data as pointed out by @Rarst.

Comment: i want to delete by using query and i have tried this query and it delete from wp option table but not from acctually delete transient ....so want to update option table do you know how to write that query?